# Why can't I import X using environment A while it works in environment B

Tags: python

I've been using Python's module *X* in *environment B* {command line, REPL, Emacs' `python-mode`, IPython, Pycharm, Jupyter's notebook etc etc etc} for a while but now when I try, in *environment A*

```
import puffoburlone
```

I receive this nasty error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'puffoburlone'
```

but it still works perfectly in *environment B* !!!

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The info you provided is not enough to definitely answer your question but I suspect that you have different Python installs and that *environment A* uses a Python different from the one used by *environment B*.

If I'm right you can solve your issue installing *X* from inside *environment A* but in some cases you must exert extra care, especially in the case of the notebook, where the kernel's Python could be different from the one that is invoked from a shell escape.

[This post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) from Jake VanderPlas addresses the notebook problem and a similar approach can be used also for different environments (`sys` is your friend)

```
# Conda install
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} numpy

# Pip install
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

In the first case we let `conda` know where the running kernel expects to find its modules, in the second one we use *the recommended way of installing modules with `pip`* making sure that the executable that runs `pip` is the executable that runs the current kernel. (For all the details I address you to the excellent post of VanderPlas).

---

If the approach I've suggested doesn't work, please obtain the following info from *inside* the two environments and *edit* your question including it, as it may help in spotting the real problem:

- `sys.version`
- `sys.executable`
- `sys.path`